# Matching with specific cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, matching, string-matching

In a weighted graph $G(\mathcal{V},\mathcal{E})$ where $w(i,j)$ is the weight of the edge $(i,j) \in \mathcal{E}$. How can I find a maximum weighted matching with a specific size (i.e specific cardinality).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me start by answering a slightly different question:
Given a weighted graph $G=(V,E)$ on $n=|V|$ vertices, we want to find a maximum-weight matching of cardinality **at most** $k$.

Let $L$ be the largest edge weight in $G$, and define $L' = 2nL$. Transform the graph $G$ by adding $\ell =n-2k$ new vertices $v_1, \dots, v_\ell$, and all edges in $\{v_1, \dots, v_\ell\} \times V$. Each new edge has weight $2nL$. Let $G'$ be the new graph.
Compute a maximum matching $M$ of $G'$ and return the matching $M \cap E$.

**If there is a matching $M$ of weight $\ell L' + x$ in $G'$ then there is a matching of weight $x$ and size at most $k$ in $G$.**

There are exactly $\ell$ edges in $M' = M \cap (\{v_1, \dots, v_\ell\} \times V)$ since at most $\ell$ edges in $\{v_1, \dots, v_\ell\} \times V$ can belong to any single matching and, if $|M| < \ell$, the weight of $M$ would be at most $(\ell-1)L' + \frac{n+\ell}{2}L < (\ell-1)L' + nL < \ell L'$.
Then, there are at most $k$ edges in $M'' = M \setminus M' = M \cap E$ as otherwise we would have $|M| = |M'| + |M''|  > \ell + k = \frac{\ell}{2} + \frac{\ell}{2} + k = \frac{\ell}{2} + \frac{n}{2} - k + k =  \frac{\ell + n}{2}$, which is a contradiction.
Since the weight of $M'$ is exactly $\ell L'$, the weight of $M'' \subseteq E$ must be $x$.

**If there is a matching $M''$ of weight $x$ and size at most $k$ in $G$ then there is a matching $M$ of weight $\ell L' + x$ in $G'$.**

Since $|M''| \le k$, there are at least $n-2k= \ell$ distinct unmatched vertices $u_1, \dots, u_\ell$ in $V$ (w.r.t. $M''$).
Choose $M = M'' \cup \{ (v_i, u_i)  \mid i=1, \dots, \ell\}$. The weight of $M$ is $\ell L' + x$.

---

We can now look for a maximum-weight matching of cardinality **exactly** $k$ in $G$.
We can reduce this problem to the one of finding a maximum-weight matching of cardinality **at most** $k$.

Given $G=(V,E)$ let $L$ be its largest edge weight.
Modify $G$ by changing the weight $w(u,v)$ of each edge $(u,v)$ to $w'(u,v) = w(u,v) + kL$. Call $G'$ the resulting graph. Find a maximum-weight matching $M$ of cardinality at most $k$ in $G'$. If $|M| < k$, the instance has no feasible solution, otherwise return $M$.

Clearly a matching $M$ of size $k$ in $G'$ weighs $kL + x$ if and only if $M$ weighs $x$ in $G$. We only need to show that: 1) if a matching of size $k$ exists in $G$, $M$ contains exactly $k$ edges, and 2) if no feasible matching exists in $G$, $M$ contains less than $k$ edges.

The second claim is immediate since any matching in $G'$ is also a matching in $G$. We then focus on the first claim:

**If $G$ admits a matching of size $k$, $M$ contains exactly $k$ edges**

By construction $|M| \le k$. We now show  that $|M| \ge k$. Suppose towards a contradiction that $M < k$. Then the weight of $M$ is at most
$\sum_{(u,v) \in M} w'(u,v) \le  (k+1) |M| L \le (k+1)(k-1)L = (k^2 - 1)L < k^2 L$. Since a weight of at least $k^2 L$ is attainable by selecting the edges in any matching of size $k$ in $G'$ (such a matching exists in $G$ and hence in $G'$), this contradicts the fact that $M$ is a maximum-weight matching.

.